pyinstaller onefile with an excel file
hi sorry for bad english so i'm making a simple inventory program that saves its data to excell file when i use pyinstaller and include the excell file when i run the exe file its throw this exception
this is the code
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl
import re
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path


def load_data():
    global workbook, sheet, list_values,path
    path = "db.xlsx"
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.active
    list_values = list(sheet.values)
    for col_name in list_values[0]:
        treeView.heading(col_name, text=col_name)
    for value_tuple in list_values[1:]:
        treeView.insert("", tk.END, values=value_tuple)


def insert_row():
    product = product_entry.get()
    price1 = int(price1_entry.get())
    price2 = int(price2_entry.get())
    print(product)
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.active
    row_values = [product, price1, price2]
    sheet.append(row_values)
    workbook.save(path)
    treeView.insert("", tk.END, values=row_values,)

    product_entry.delete(0, "end")
    product_entry.insert(0, "اسم المنتج")
    price1_entry.delete(0, "end")
    price1_entry.insert(0, "سعر الجملة")
    price2_entry.delete(0, "end")
    price2_entry.insert(0, "سعر البيع")


.................


i tried changing the pyinstaller to one file tried deffrint selected files and some random thing it didn't work

This question is similar to: How to set up relative paths to make a portable .exe build in PyInstaller with Python 3?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
